# Heroku error: heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"?

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-api

I'm trying to deploy very simple Nodejs API on Heroku, but I can't seem to figure out why it keeps on giving me this error. The app runs just fine on local server, even with `heroku local web`. My app is listening on `app.listen( process.env.PORT || 5500 );`.

**Here is my error when I** `heroku logs --tail`.

```
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912659+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-01.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912659+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912659+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912660+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912660+00:00 app[web.1]: compatibilityError: null,
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912660+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912660+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912661+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912661+00:00 app[web.1]: commonWireVersion: null
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912661+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T03:09:40.912662+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T03:09:41.093698+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-22T03:09:46.165964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-22T03:09:46.168346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-22T03:09:49.527931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-10-22T03:10:23.122929+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123001+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:800:32)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123006+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123010+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123015+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123019+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123020+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123020+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:14:10)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123020+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123020+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123021+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123021+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123021+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123022+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123026+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123026+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123026+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123027+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSetVersion: null,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123027+00:00 app[web.1]: maxElectionId: null,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123027+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(3) {
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123027+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123028+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123028+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-01.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123033+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123033+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123033+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123033+00:00 app[web.1]: compatibilityError: null,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123034+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123034+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123034+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123034+00:00 app[web.1]: commonWireVersion: null
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123035+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T03:10:23.123035+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T03:10:23.187310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-22T03:10:23.226782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-22T03:10:24.274124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=2e574211-23f3-423c-8322-2ec071a7f798 fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:10:25.104524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/app" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=53362476-b37c-487e-9453-0cce7aa0033d fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:10:25.478442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=a8c9df8f-4bfc-44a8-8061-ce6e0950f431 fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:10:26.329468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=8d56ea2d-257c-4118-9451-b454e59651f7 fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:10:30.517993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/app" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=8ae82052-e3d2-410c-90ed-e92e522acdeb fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:10:30.857187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=ff3b48e6-6712-4ab8-8937-07b0329fb97c fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:13:50.120474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=a94ad607-4349-44be-af8d-14d8cb31a497 fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:13:50.386222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=596442ac-c410-4c21-ab4b-fba6a358215f fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-22T03:14:46.201472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-22T03:14:48.884957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-10-22T03:15:21.469714+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477855+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:800:32)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477862+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477867+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477871+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477876+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:14:10)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477878+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477878+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477878+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477884+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477884+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477884+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477885+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSetVersion: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477885+00:00 app[web.1]: maxElectionId: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477885+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(3) {
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477886+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477886+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477886+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-01.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477891+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477878+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477878+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477878+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477884+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477884+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477884+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477885+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSetVersion: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477885+00:00 app[web.1]: maxElectionId: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477885+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(3) {
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477886+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477886+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477886+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-01.4mqda.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477891+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477892+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477892+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477892+00:00 app[web.1]: compatibilityError: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477893+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477893+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477893+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477893+00:00 app[web.1]: commonWireVersion: null
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477894+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T03:15:21.477894+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-22T03:15:21.561613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-22T03:15:21.656462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-22T03:15:23.967387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=adak.herokuapp.com request_id=fe070797-e414-40c8-aeac-957b78fec27b fwd="98.219.228.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Here is error on browser console:**
[image]

**Procfile:**

```
web: node index.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "adak-v3-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
    "serve": "^11.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

What am I missing? I've tried many things surfing on Stackoverflow but nothing helped yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to make a connection-

```
mongoose.connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(res=>{
            console.log("DB Connected!")
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(Error, err.message);
    })
```

If using the above code-
You need to whitelist the heroku IP address b going to MongoDB Atlas.
Ip Addres to be added is- '0.0.0.0/0'

Comment: Adding IP was it! Thak you so much!